# Poor performance issue when drawing lines on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, draw

I'm developing an application which has a part that allows you to draw using your fingers.

To do that I've followed this tutorial (here's also the app with the source code):
http://sigurdsnorteland.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/fingerpaint-a-little-wp7-paint-app/

And this (almost the same):
http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-2-drawing-shapes-with-finger

The problem (for both) is that if I draw a lot of lines the application becomes very slow making impossible to draw normally. Does this happen because I create too many lines that are kept in memory? And how can I solve this? I've seen many applications on the market that don't suffer of this issue...

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: I didn't really read everything provided in the links, but I'm fairly certain the reason your code is slow, is because you're drawing *each and every line individually*.

Comment: Exactly... Is there another way to do that?

Comment: To be honest, WP development is unknown territory to me, but maybe this link helps: http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-3-understanding-path-shapes